# Help me decide the artboard size in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, illustrator-effects, information-graphics

I use Adobe Illustrator for my work and I am in the process of designing an infographic which needs to be printed and also put on the web.

I understand that I would be needing a 300ppi and 72ppi resolution respectively. For printing, the size should be A4.

Would it be wise if i create a 595px by 842px artboard and save it in 72ppi and 300ppi. Or, should i create a 2480px by 3508px artboard and save it in 72ppi and 300ppi.

Comment: Why would you save the artwork as a raster for print?

Comment: Why would you need to have a lower size/resolution for web? Don't you want your infographic to be high-quality and readable?

Comment: Hi Vaishali. Welcome to GDSE. Web browsers ignore the dpi/ppi setting - so the number you set it at is irrelevant. All that matters on the web is the size of the image in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

If the infographic is made entirely in vector, the dimensions are relative, but if it contains raster elements you can create a artboard of 210 x 297 mm (8.3 × 11.7 in) at 300 ppi or 2480 x 3508 px.

If it is required that both the printed and on screen results are homogeneous, I suggest you to work since the beginning in CMYK.

Comment: The infographic does not have any raster images. In that case, can I make an artboard of 595px*842px and save it in 72ppi and 300ppi for screen and print respectively?

Comment: @Vaishali For on-screen viewing, it depends on many factors, such as if it's to be displayed on high pixel density devices.
For printing you can use a artboard 595 x 842 px but once finished you have to make it suitable for print format (A4) and then save it to 300ppi or deliver the vector file to the printing services. My advice is first to contact the printing services, to get all the details.

Comment: @Vaishali Perfect! Don't forget to accept the answer :)